# Displaying data on a website based on selection in a dropdown box

Tags: javascript, jsf

I have the following problem:

In my data model I have a class called *Type*. *Type* consists of a title and a description.

Now I have a dropdown box in which the user may select an instance of *Type*:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="typeDropdown" onchange="displayDescription();">
      <f:selectItems value="#{operationCreator.types.title}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Below the dropdown box is a div area in which I want the description of the selected *Type* displayed.

My question is the following:

How can I store the description of the *Type* instances in javascript? A simple JSF tag which iterates over the list would do the job, but unfortunately I know of none. They all print additional HTML tags (like datatable), or work only with surrounding JSF tags (like selectItems).

I do know I could fix my problem using AJAX push, but I don't want to. I want to access my data on page load in javascript.

I hope you can help me!
Thanks, Michael

Comment: The nature of this question (a relatively clumsy attempt to solve a problem which is in JSF 2.x to be solved by only one additional tag) indicates that you're still on the old JSF 1.x. Is this true?

Comment: No, I am using the latest JSF version. However I am new to JSF, so any hints and tipps on how to do it in a complete different way are appreciated! My only restriction is to avoid ajax.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid ajax? That's exactly the solution to your problem.

Comment: The site will be displayed on mobile clients. Because of latency issues AJAX is out of scope.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Prepare the data in JSON format and let JSF just print it as a JS variable. You could do that *either* directly in backing bean

```java
public String getTypesAsJson() {
    return typesAsJson;
}
```

with

```html
<script>
    var types = #{bean.typesAsJson};
</script>
```

*or* in the view by iterating over a Java collection like `List<Type>` and printing the JavaScript code accordingly if the values are guaranteed to not contain any special characters in JS such as quotes and newlines:

```html
<script>
    var types = {
        <ui:repeat value="#{bean.types}" var="type" varStatus="loop">
            "#{type.title}": "#{type.description}"#{!loop.last ? "," : ""}
        </ui:repeat>
    };
</script>
```

The first way is preferable as it eliminates the risk for syntax errors in the produced JS code when the type title or description contains a JS special character. You can use among others [Google Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to convert a Java collection of beans to a string in valid JSON format.

```java
typesAsJson = new Gson().toJson(types);
```

Now, if you make sure that the item value of the dropdownlist is the type title, then you can get the associated description as follows

```html
<h:selectOneMenu ... onchange="displayDescription(this)">
```

with

```js
function displayDescription(dropdown) {
    var title = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
    var description = types[title];
    // ...
}
```